# How is it possible that I am able to call nested len() function inside outer() function

Tags: python, scope, nested, namespaces

Im learning python namespace & Scope and for that I am following [This](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html#1-lg---local-and-global-scopes) Tutorial. It ends with a challenge to predict what the following code will output.

```
a = 'global'

def outer():

    def len(in_var):
        print('called my len() function: ', end="")
        l = 0
        for i in in_var:
            l += 1
        return l

    a = 'local'

    def inner():
        global len
        nonlocal a
        a += ' variable'
    inner()
    print('a is', a)
    print(len(a))


outer()

print(len(a))
print('a is', a)
```

My question about the block of code above is: How is it possible that we can call the len() function inside outer()? So, why does print(len(a)) call the len() function inside outer()?

When I try to call a nested function, like I did below, it will not work. Can someone enlighten me?:

```
print("Does my Inner get called automatically if I call my outer?")

def outer():

    def inner():
        print("Yes")


outer() #A call to outer does not call inner() automatically
print(inner()) #Gives a NameError
```

Comment: In first code snippet, you call string `len()` function (built-in), not `len()` inside `outer()`. Hence, no `NameError`.

Comment: You define `len` inside `outer` and you also call it there. If not from there, where else could you call it from?

Comment: @Austin That's what I tought also, but usually my IDE (Pycharm) turns built-in function calls blue. That didn't happen, and when I ctrl-clicked len in print(len(a)) It jumped to the len() function inside outer. That's why I tought it was calling the len() inside outer. Lesson learned: Don't rely on IDE's too heavily. Thanks.

Comment: @Psychotechnopath, You have an output to verify which function is called. Have you looked at your output?

Comment: @Austin Yes but because the nested/global stuff is still relatively new for me I couldn't make sense of it. Thx to your comment now I can.

Comment: @deceze I was thinking from outside the outer() function, but that doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to call a function that is nested inside another function from outside both of those functions?

Comment: In short: no. For starters, anything defined inside a function is only defined while the function is running, and doesn’t exist while it’s not running. So by definition there’s no way to access anything inside a function while it’s not currently executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the `print(len(a))` was calling the function `len(in_var)` inside `outer()`. Therefore I got confused, because I wasn't able to call nested functions myself. However, as it turns out, `print(len(a))` Is calling the *built-in* version of `len()`, so not the one inside `outer()`. And it isn't possible to directly call nested functions from "outside" of the function inside which the function is nested. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the b() function is defined inside a() function. Which means, it is living inside a(). Whenever we go outside of a() then b() gets destroyed. So it is available within that scope only. Outside of that, it is not available.

```
def a():
    def b():
        print("inside b")
    b() // no error

a()
b() // error. As you are trying to access something which is not available there.
```